# Errores al crear mi pagina web en html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me están saliendo dos errores con unos .js a la hora de crear mi pagina.

Estos .js son

> public.common.js

y

> jquery-1.10.2.min.js

En el public es un error con `"getAttribute"` y en el jquery es con el `"autocomplete is not a function"`.
Algún consejo rápido para arreglar esto por favor.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Puedes mostrar los errores que te muestra en la consola?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at CommonJS (public.common.js:14)
    at public.common.js:139
CommonJS @ public.common.js:14
(anonymous) @ public.common.js:139
Tienda Vargas Bolsa de Trabajo.html:478 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Tienda Vargas Bolsa de Trabajo.html:478)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)

Comment: actualiza tu version de jquery estas usando una version muy vieja ya

Comment: autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Tienda Vargas Bolsa de Trabajo.html:478)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que dar más detalles para poderte ayudar, respecto a jquery, deberías haber usado una función que no está registrada, es decir, que no has cargado una plugin de jquery de autocompletado.

```js
$(#identificador).autocomplete(...)   //No si no tienes un plugin de autocompletado con el mismo nombre de función.
```

Comment: Son querys que un amigo usó para crear lo mismo, solo que al él si le funcionaron y a mi no. Es exactamente el mismo query. Pero veré que puedo hacer con tu consejo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa esta página, para que entiendas para que se usa el autocompletado y ya entiendas que debes estar haciendo en tu página, ya que si no explicas en qué lo usas no te podemos ayudar con claridad: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Yo nunca dudo que jqueryui sea una solución, pero a veces queremos hacer más cosas y por solo conocer un poco nos limitamos. Puedes obtener muchas más funcionalidades con esta lib http://easyautocomplete.com/ que también es de autocompletado, pero te permite multiples cosas, además de poseer una buena guía. Realmente espero que resuelvas.

Comment: npmPath = /^[a-zA-Z_-]/,
      __filename = info._ || el.getAttribute('data-main').replace(npmPath, './$&'),
      normalize = function (url) {          ese es principalmente el error